# Stripe webhook how to get f.... product ID or NAME or something data which help me identify what exact user bought

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

In payment_intent.succeeded I got a lot useless data, BUT CAN NOT FIND JUST ID OF PRODUCT USER BUY. This is obviously what 90% devs need, why can't this be added instead of a bunch of unnecessary information ????????????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PaymentIntents weren't designed to work with Prices/Products, they are a "[lower level" object](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/tour#payment-objects) intended to create a payment for an "amount".

You are likely using Stripe Checkout for one time payments which does work with Products/Prices. Checkout generates a PaymentIntent under the hood to facilitate the payment. The Product or Price details won't be obtained from the `payment_intent.succeeded` event but rather, from the `checkout.session.completed` webhook event.

When you receive that event, you need to [retrieve the Checkout Session object and "expand"](https://stripe.com/docs/expand#includable-properties) the `line_items` field to obtain all the line items passed to Checkout and the underlying Prices and Products by passing `expand: ["line_items.data.price.product"]`